# if code in python 3.3.3 (count odd, positive values !!?)

Tags: python, python-3.3

my code is about :count how many values are even , positive , negative
and it's not working :
thanks for your help

```
e = [ ] 

for c in range(5):

    c=float(input())
    if c<0:
        e.append(c)
        print("{} valor(es) negativo(s)".format(len(e)))
    if c>0:
        e.append(c)
        print("{} valor(es) positivo(s)".format(len(e)))
    if c%2!=0:
        e.append(c)
        print("{} valor(es) par(es)".format(len(e)))
    if c%2==0:
        e.append(c)
        print("{} valor(es) impar(es)".format(len(e)))
```

i want the o/p like this :

3 valor(es) par(es)

2 valor(es) impar(es)

1 valor(es) positivo(s)

3 valor(es) negativo(s)

when i enter the five ( int )nos 
and exit when input==4

Comment: Ok, so... Are you getting an error or something? What's your question?

Comment: Please revise your question and be more specific about what your problem is? What is currently not working in your code? What is it doing that you think it should not be doing? What are the inputs and expected outputs? Please make sure you meet the requirements of a [mcve]

Comment: Yes. Please specify a question.

Comment: And your problem is? You're not even using `elif` in this code.

Comment: And why do you add each value to `e` one or two times?

Comment: Are you asking how to use `elif`?

Comment: @MahaTaha: What is it doing? What do you want it to do? "Not working" could mean anything from "Getting an exception" to "I'm missing a comma in the output".

Comment: So why not just say its not working in your question, rather then beating around the bush.

Comment: Also note, `n%2 != 0` is not really testing what you might think; I'm assuming you're trying to distinguish even and odd numbers, but even and odd don't make sense for arbitrary `float` values; is `12.5` even or odd? `12.5 % 2` produces `0.5`, so it will count as odd (as will every value that isn't an even integer value, and depending on floating point precision issues, possibly some even integer values too). Did you mean to convert to `int`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger ... i edited my Q

Answer (score 2):

First you are using the same list for all value types. Count will be correct only the first time! see below for odd & even numbers. Same error above for positive / negative.

Second this is functionnaly wrong:

```
if c%2!=0:
    e.append(c)
    print("{} valor(es) par(es)".format(len(e)))
if c%2==0:
    e.append(c)
    print("{} valor(es) impar(es)".format(len(e)))
```

Define:

```
pares = []
impares = []
```

in your loop, write this

```
if c%2==0:
    pares.append(c)
    print("{} valor(es) par(es)".format(len(pares)))
else:
    impares.append(c)
    print("{} valor(es) impar(es)".format(len(impares)))
```

proof of concept and trying to be as pythonic as possible
(I have made the example non-interactive, and using only integers. Like ShadowRanger noted, modulo on floats won't work very well with this code)

```
# define 4 lists
the_list = [list() for i in range(4)]
negative_values,positive_values,odd_values,even_values = the_list

z=[1,2,-5,-7,0,3,-4]
for c in z: #range(5):

    #c=float(input())
    if c<0:
        negative_values.append(c)
    elif c>0:
        positive_values.append(c)
    if c%2==0:
        even_values.append(c)
    else:
        odd_values.append(c)

print("{} negative values, {} positive values, {} odd values, {} even values".format(*tuple(len(x) for x in the_list)))
```

Comment: Where are you getting `pares` and `impares` from?

Comment: I just define them above, using my spanish skills :)

Comment: Ok. But you might want to add that to your answer ;)... Oh wait, you already did while I was typing this comment.

Comment: nope, I improved it (moved from the end to the middle) when I saw your comment.

Comment: not exactly what i want :/ ... i edit my Q

Comment: yup .. it's working but i can't find good source to understand (Tuple)

Comment: just a way of enumerating all the lists and pass them to format as 4 arguments. Simpler things can be done but python is powerful so I just used that.

Comment: i have Q : how to stop all code when input==4 ??! @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: just `if input==4: break`